# How to return a single row with a total using a sql query and or expressions in sql server

Tags: jquery, sql, reporting-services, dataset, report

I have a query that I have written to return a total of all payments. What is happening is that when I run my report it is returnng multiple rows instead of one row and I think this is because of the groupby clause I have in my query.
The thing is it seems I need to have the group by because some of the fields are included in my dataset for example I actually filter using the transaction date so I cannot ommit it. This is my query below

```
select distinct Transaction_Amount, Transaction_Type, Transaction_Date  --'R '+ CONVERT(varchar,SUM(Transaction_Amount)) as [Epurse Credits/Deposits]
from Transactional_Account
where Transaction_Type like '%credit%'
```

Even when I place my expression as `=SUM(Fields!Transaction_Amount.Value,"DataSet1")` the result set still contains multiple rows

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per transaction, then remove the `DISTINCT` and use aggregation functions:

```
select max(Transaction_Amount), max(Transaction_Type), max(Transaction_Date)
      sum(Transaction_Amount) as [Epurse Credits/Deposits]
from Transactional_Account
where Transaction_Type like '%credit%';
```

This returns arbitrary (well, the maximum) values for each of the other columns.  But you are guaranteed one row.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include your total in your dataset query. Just add a row group to your table/matrix in the report design  (or change the existing 'details' row group), and group by all the common fields that you need to show.